# How can I convert Json key:value into value:value in C#?

Tags: c#, json, key-value

I am reading a resource file in C# and converted it to the JSON string format. Now I want to convert that JSON string's value as keys.

Example,

```
[
 {
  "key": "CreateAccount",
  "text": "Create Account"
 },
 {
  "key": "EmailAddress",
  "text": "Email Address"
 }
]
```

So I just want to make the above json string into "Key:text" as like below,

```
[
 {
  "CreateAccount": "Create Account"
 },
 {
  "EmailAddress": "Email Address"
 }
]
```

My C#,

```
var obj = new
 {
   Lang=XElement.Parse(_FileDataAsText)
    .Elements("data")
    .Select(el => new
          {
                    key= el.Attribute("name").Value,
                    text = el.Element("value").Value
          }.ToList()
 };

 string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```

Comment: convert to dictionary..

Comment: @Dennis, I just want to make that JSON data and give it to my another UI team via API. So they will extract & bind the JSON string data in UI side, for that I wanted to make the json format like 'value':'value'.  No need to bother about the Deserialization part.

Comment: @Harishr that's a nice idea but can you provide simple example code or sample ?

Comment: @Dennis, Yes, I just want to convert as an above format and I will give them. This is for dynamic binding.

Answer (score 2):

Create a class to represent the inner JSON objects:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Then deserialize the JSON array to `List<RootObject>` using [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json), project the object `key` and `text` to key value pairs inside a `Dictionary<string, string>` using [`Enumerable.Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netcore-3.1), then serialize the result as `List<Dictionary<string, string>>`.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

...

var json = @"[{""key"": ""CreateAccount"",""text"": ""Create Account""},{""key"": ""EmailAddress"",""text"": ""Email Address""}]";

 var deserializedJson = JsonConvert
    .DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(json);

var result = deserializedJson
    .Select(obj => new Dictionary<string, string> { 
        { obj.Key, obj.Text } 
    })
    .ToList();

var serializedJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result, Formatting.Indented);

Console.WriteLine(serializedJson);
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "CreateAccount": "Create Account"
  },
  {
    "EmailAddress": "Email Address"
  }
]
```